# ReactJS - Handsontable - determine changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

I am trying to get values of what has changed in `react-handsontable` Component I am using:

```
<HotTable root="hot"
                data={this.state.handsontableData}
                colHeaders={this.handsontableColumns}
                rowHeaders={true}
                width="1200"
                height="300"
                stretchH="all"
                colWidths={this.handsontableColWidths}
                onAfterChange={this.handleHOTChange(changes, source)} />
```

But, `onAfterChange={this.handleHOTChange(changes, source)}` throws error:

```
./src/MyComponent.jsx
  Line 73:  'changes' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 73:  'source' is not defined   no-undef
```

Can please someone tell me how can I get "changes" from event?

If I just use `onAfterChange={this.handleHOTChange}` without arguments then `handleHOTchanges` function gets invoked on change. But then how do I determine what has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, got this fixed:

Below is solution:

```
<HotTable root="hot"
                data={this.state.handsontableData}
                colHeaders={this.handsontableColumns}
                rowHeaders={true}
                width="1200"
                height="300"
                stretchH="all"
                colWidths={this.handsontableColWidths}
                onAfterChange={(changes, source) => this.handleHOTChange(changes, source)} />
```

Key was to use arrow function syntax: `(changes, source) => this.handleHOTChange(changes, source)`

and below is example handler function to print argument received in console:

```
handleHOTChange(changes, source) {
     alert('changed!');
     console.log(changes);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you should pass in a function, *NOT* call a function. the answer above works but I can consider not right and redundant. It is creating a function that only calls another function *this.handleHOTChange* also the explanation isn't that because you need to use arrow function syntax. you can actually use other syntax like

```

```
<HotTable root="hot"
                data={this.state.handsontableData}
                colHeaders={this.handsontableColumns}
                rowHeaders={true}
                width="1200"
                height="300"
                stretchH="all"
                colWidths={this.handsontableColWidths}
                onAfterChange={function(changes, source){
                   // do something....}
```

```
2nd. to simplify this one. you can just do.

```
<HotTable root="hot"
            data={this.state.handsontableData}
            colHeaders={this.handsontableColumns}
            rowHeaders={true}
            width="1200"
            height="300"
            stretchH="all"
            colWidths={this.handsontableColWidths}
            onAfterChange={this.handleHOTChange} />
```

expecting that handleHotChange is a *function*